# Why does Lift use xml.Node instead of xml.Elem?

Tags: xml, scala, lift

`scala.xml.Elem` is a subclass of `scala.xml.Node`. `scala.xml.XML.loadFile` loads a whole XML document into a `scala.xml.Elem`. So why does Lift use `scala.xml.Node` in this case and in what cases could I prefer `scala.xml.Node` over `scala.xml.Elem`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you answered it in your question: `Elem` is a subclass of `Node` or, in reverse, `Node` is the superclass of `Elem`. There are many methods (in the Scala standard library or in Lift) that return `Node` or `NodeSeq` (which is basically the same thing), and so I imagine that is why `Node` is preferred to `Elem`. But if you want an authoritative answer I'd recommend asking David [on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb).

Comment: I've just supposed an appropriate specialized type should be always preferred over a more generic one and I've got this question as soon as I've realized that my code seem to have no place where there is to be Node but not Elem (logically).

Comment: Yeah, the organization of the Scala XML library can be quite hairy occasionally.